# Limit on Action Change in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'd like to build **an autonomous ship** in a virtual environment **using DDPG**.

However, the problem is that there's an action space of (-180', +180') for steering, and DDPG would be able to choose -180' at (t-1) and +180' at (t+1), which is impossible in the real world. (basically, you can't rotate a steering wheel that fast.)

---

The possible solution that I thought was this.

1. Set a maximum steering rate (e.g. 10' per step)
2. If the taken action gets out of an available action range of (current_steeringWheel_angle - 10', current_steeringWheel_angle + 10'), change the taken action to the end value in the available action range
3. Take a step with the changed action in the virtual environment.
4. (1st option) update the DDPG with the changed action.
   (2nd option) update the DDPG with the originally taken action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

---

#### 1st reference :

[image]
(src: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378008/how-to-handle-a-changing-action-space-in-reinforcement-learning/378025#378025?newreg=09ef385b87a54f27b5011f983dbf0270)

#### 2nd reference (basically, it'stalking about the same thing as above.) :

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328835/enforcing-game-rules-in-alpha-go-zero

---